# How to Install pytorch stable on Book2 laptop (GeForce 1060 gpu)?

Tags: windows, pytorch

I had this working before updating conda and after several tries. I have a book2 with
Windows 11 Version  10.0.22621 Build 22621
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz, 2112 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Microsoft Corporation 394.779.768, 8/11/2015.

Lately I updated NVidia drivers from 537.58-notebook-win10-win11-64bit-international-nsd-dch-whql.exe which I thought would give me 12.1 drivers but:
nvidia-smi.exe
Sat Oct 21 09:43:45 2023
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 537.58                 Driver Version: 537.58       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060      WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   29C    P2              21W /  54W |      0MiB /  6144MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

As suggested to run a conda installP
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia

I get inconsistencies:

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

- defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py38_1
- conda-forge/win-64::cfitsio==4.1.0=h5a969a9_0
- conda-forge/noarch::datashader==0.14.4=pyh1a96a4e_0
- conda-forge/win-64::imagecodecs==2022.2.22=py38h6acac19_4
- conda-forge/win-64::numba==0.56.4=py38hb182ae8_1
- conda-forge/win-64::scikit-image==0.19.2=py38h5d928e2_0
- conda-forge/noarch::tifffile==2023.4.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- defaults/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2023.03=py38_0
  unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
  Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
  Solving environment: /
  The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
  The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
- defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py38_1
- conda-forge/noarch::dask==2022.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- conda-forge/noarch::datashader==0.14.4=pyh1a96a4e_0
  *- conda-forge/noarch::distributed==2022.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0*
- conda-forge/win-64::imagecodecs==2022.2.22=py38h6acac19_4
  *- conda-forge/noarch::intake==0.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0*
- conda-forge/win-64::numba==0.56.4=py38hb182ae8_1
- conda-forge/win-64::scikit-image==0.19.2=py38h5d928e2_0
- conda-forge/noarch::tifffile==2023.4.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0

installing ...

spyder-kernels-2.4.1 | 78 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-cupti-12.1.105  | 11.6 MB   | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-profiler-api-12 | 19 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
libcufft-dev-11.0.2. | 102.6 MB  | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-cccl-12.3.52    | 1.4 MB    | ########################################## | 100%
imagecodecs-2023.1.2 | 8.9 MB    | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-opencl-12.3.52  | 11 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
pyviz_comms-2.3.2    | 45 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
qdarkstyle-3.0.3     | 313 KB    | ########################################## | 100%
torchaudio-2.0.2     | 5.4 MB    | ########################################## | 100%
torchvision-0.15.2   | 6.5 MB    | ######################################### | 100%
cuda-libraries-12.1. | 1 KB      | ########################################## | 100%
spyder-5.4.1         | 10.5 MB   | ########################################## | 100%
libnvjitlink-12.1.10 | 67.3 MB   | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-libraries-dev-1 | 1 KB      | ########################################## | 100%
libcurand-dev-10.3.4 | 49.8 MB   | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-nvtx-12.1.105   | 41 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-cudart-12.1.105 | 964 KB    | ########################################## | 100%
libnvjpeg-dev-12.1.1 | 2.4 MB    | ########################################## | 100%
cfitsio-3.470        | 596 KB    | ########################################## | 100%
pytorch-2.0.1        | 145.5 MB  | #########################################7 | 100%
libcusolver-dev-11.4 | 95.7 MB   | ########################################## | 100%
jupyter_client-7.3.4 | 91 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
libnvjitlink-dev-12. | 13.8 MB   | ########################################## | 100%
libcufft-11.0.2.4    | 6 KB      | ########################################## | 100%
libcusparse-12.0.2.5 | 12 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
libcusolver-11.4.4.5 | 30 KB     | ########################################## | 100%
cuda-opencl-dev-12.3 | 61 KB     | ########################################## | 100%

now I have:
conda list -n base | grep torch
pytorch                   2.0.1               py3.8_cpu_0    pytorch
pytorch-cuda              12.1                 hde6ce7c_5    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
torch                     2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi

conda list -n base | grep cuda
cuda-cccl                 12.3.52                       0    nvidia
cuda-cudart               12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-cudart-dev           12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-cupti                12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-libraries            12.1.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-libraries-dev        12.1.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc                12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc-dev            12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-nvtx                 12.1.105                      0    nvidia
cuda-opencl               12.3.52                       0    nvidia
cuda-opencl-dev           12.3.52                       0    nvidia
cuda-profiler-api         12.3.52                       0    nvidia
cuda-runtime              12.1.0                        0    nvidia
pytorch-cuda              12.1                 hde6ce7c_5    pytorch

when I run:
python -u ensemble_testing.py ....
I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ensemble_testing.py", line 4, in 
import torch
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch_*init*_.py", line 122, in 
raise err
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\nvfuser_codegen.dll" or one of its dependencies.

I suspect "pytorch                   **2.0.1**               py3.8_cpu_0    pytorch"

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Steve

See above explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work through several different packages and installs. I'm posting the final environment.yml that works using the GPU for my model. Here is the contents of the .yml to create a conda environment that will run a pytorch model and can use the gpu using the code

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
```

on a Surface Book2 laptop. Note that the environment name is your choice, I just made it explicit for the OS and processor.

```
name: win11pytorchgpu
channels:
  - pytorch
  - nvidia/label/cuda-12.1.0
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - albumentations=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - blas=2.119=mkl
  - blas-devel=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - brotli=1.1.0=hcfcfb64_1
  - brotli-bin=1.1.0=hcfcfb64_1
  - brotli-python=1.1.0=py38hd3f51b4_1
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h8ffe710_4
  - ca-certificates=2023.7.22=h56e8100_0
  - click=8.1.7=win_pyh7428d3b_0
  - cloudpickle=3.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - contourpy=1.1.1=py38hb1fd069_1
  - cuda=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-cccl=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-command-line-tools=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-compiler=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-cudart=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-cudart-dev=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-cuobjdump=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-cupti=12.1.62=0
  - cuda-cuxxfilt=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-demo-suite=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-documentation=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-libraries=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-libraries-dev=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-nsight-compute=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-nvcc=12.1.66=0
  - cuda-nvdisasm=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-nvml-dev=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-nvprof=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-nvprune=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-nvrtc=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-nvrtc-dev=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-nvtx=12.1.66=0
  - cuda-nvvp=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-opencl=12.1.56=0
  - cuda-opencl-dev=12.1.56=0
  - cuda-profiler-api=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-runtime=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-sanitizer-api=12.1.55=0
  - cuda-toolkit=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-tools=12.1.0=0
  - cuda-visual-tools=12.1.0=0
  - cycler=0.12.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cython=3.0.4=py38hd3f51b4_0
  - cytoolz=0.12.2=py38h91455d4_1
  - dask-core=2022.12.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - docker-pycreds=0.4.0=py_0
  - eigen=3.4.0=h91493d7_0
  - enum34=1.1.10=py38h32f6830_2
  - fonttools=4.43.1=py38h91455d4_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=hdaf720e_2
  - gettext=0.21.1=h5728263_0
  - gitdb=4.0.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gitpython=3.1.40=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - glib=2.78.0=h12be248_0
  - glib-tools=2.78.0=h12be248_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.18.5=h9e645db_0
  - gstreamer=1.18.5=hd78058f_0
  - hdf5=1.10.6=nompi_he0bbb20_101
  - icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
  - idna=3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - imagecodecs-lite=2019.12.3=py38he7056a7_7
  - imageio=2.6.1=py38_0
  - importlib-resources=6.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib_resources=6.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - intel-openmp=2023.2.0=h57928b3_50496
  - jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - joblib=1.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jpeg=9e=h8ffe710_2
  - kiwisolver=1.4.5=py38hb1fd069_1
  - krb5=1.20.1=h6609f42_0
  - lerc=4.0.0=h63175ca_0
  - libabseil=20230802.1=cxx17_h63175ca_0
  - libblas=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - libbrotlicommon=1.1.0=hcfcfb64_1
  - libbrotlidec=1.1.0=hcfcfb64_1
  - libbrotlienc=1.1.0=hcfcfb64_1
  - libcblas=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - libclang=12.0.0=default_h627e005_2
  - libclang13=15.0.7=default_h77d9078_3
  - libcublas=12.1.0.26=0
  - libcublas-dev=12.1.0.26=0
  - libcufft=11.0.2.4=0
  - libcufft-dev=11.0.2.4=0
  - libcurand=10.3.2.56=0
  - libcurand-dev=10.3.2.56=0
  - libcusolver=11.4.4.55=0
  - libcusolver-dev=11.4.4.55=0
  - libcusparse=12.0.2.55=0
  - libcusparse-dev=12.0.2.55=0
  - libdeflate=1.19=hcfcfb64_0
  - libffi=3.4.2=h8ffe710_5
  - libglib=2.78.0=he8f3873_0
  - libiconv=1.17=h8ffe710_0
  - libjpeg-turbo=2.1.4=hcfcfb64_0
  - liblapack=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - liblapacke=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - libnpp=12.0.2.50=0
  - libnpp-dev=12.0.2.50=0
  - libnvjitlink=12.1.55=0
  - libnvjitlink-dev=12.1.55=0
  - libnvjpeg=12.1.0.39=0
  - libnvjpeg-dev=12.1.0.39=0
  - libnvvm-samples=12.1.55=0
  - libogg=1.3.4=h8ffe710_1
  - libpng=1.6.39=h19919ed_0
  - libprotobuf=3.20.3=h12be248_0
  - libsqlite=3.43.2=hcfcfb64_0
  - libtiff=4.2.0=h0c97f57_3
  - libuv=1.44.2=hcfcfb64_1
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=h0e60522_0
  - libwebp=1.3.2=hcfcfb64_1
  - libwebp-base=1.3.2=hcfcfb64_0
  - libxcb=1.15=hcd874cb_0
  - libxml2=2.10.4=hc3477c8_0
  - libxslt=1.1.37=h0192164_0
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hcfcfb64_5
  - locket=1.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - matplotlib=3.7.3=py38haa244fe_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.7.3=py38h2724991_0
  - mkl=2023.2.0=h6a75c08_50496
  - mkl-devel=2023.2.0=h57928b3_50496
  - mkl-include=2023.2.0=h6a75c08_50496
  - mpmath=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - munkres=1.1.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - nsight-compute=2023.1.0.15=0
  - olefile=0.46=pyh9f0ad1d_1
  - opencv=4.6.0=py38h104de81_2
  - openssl=1.1.1w=hcfcfb64_0
  - packaging=23.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - partd=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pathlib=1.0.1=py38haa244fe_7
  - pathtools=0.1.2=py_1
  - pcre2=10.40=h17e33f8_0
  - pip=23.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - platformdirs=3.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ply=3.11=py_1
  - pooch=1.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_4
  - protobuf=3.20.3=py38haa244fe_1
  - psutil=5.9.5=py38h91455d4_1
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=hcd874cb_1001
  - pthreads-win32=2.9.1=hfa6e2cd_3
  - pycocotools=2.0.6=py38hbaf524b_1
  - pyparsing=3.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyqt=5.15.7=py38hd77b12b_0
  - pyqt5-sip=12.11.0=py38hd77b12b_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyh0701188_6
  - python=3.8.5=h60c2a47_9_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python_abi=3.8=4_cp38
  - pytorch-mutex=1.0=cpu
  - pywavelets=1.4.1=py38he7056a7_1
  - pyyaml=6.0.1=py38h91455d4_1
  - qt-main=5.15.2=he8e5bd7_7
  - qt-webengine=5.15.9=h5bd16bc_7
  - qtwebkit=5.212=h2bbfb41_5
  - qudida=0.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - scikit-image=0.18.1=py38h4c96930_0
  - scikit-learn=1.3.1=py38h4f736e5_1
  - scipy=1.10.1=py38h1aea9ed_3
  - sentry-sdk=1.32.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - setproctitle=1.3.3=py38h91455d4_0
  - setuptools=68.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sip=6.6.2=py38hd77b12b_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - smmap=5.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sqlite=3.43.2=hcfcfb64_0
  - sympy=1.12=pyh04b8f61_3
  - tbb=2021.8.0=h59b6b97_0
  - threadpoolctl=3.2.0=pyha21a80b_0
  - tifffile=2019.7.26.2=py38_0
  - tk=8.6.13=hcfcfb64_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - toolz=0.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tornado=6.3.3=py38h91455d4_1
  - tqdm=4.66.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ucrt=10.0.22621.0=h57928b3_0
  - unicodedata2=15.1.0=py38h91455d4_0
  - vc=14.3=h64f974e_17
  - vc14_runtime=14.36.32532=hdcecf7f_17
  - vs2015_runtime=14.36.32532=h05e6639_17
  - wandb=0.15.12=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.41.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_6
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.11=hcd874cb_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=hcd874cb_0
  - xz=5.2.6=h8d14728_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h8ffe710_2
  - zipp=3.17.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=hcfcfb64_5
  - zstd=1.5.5=h12be248_0
  - pip:
      - certifi==2022.12.7
      - charset-normalizer==2.1.1
      - filelock==3.9.0
      - fsspec==2023.4.0
      - markupsafe==2.1.2
      - networkx==3.0
      - numpy==1.24.1
      - opencv-python==4.8.1.78
      - pillow==9.3.0
      - requests==2.28.1
      - torch==2.1.0+cu121
      - torchaudio==2.1.0+cu121
      - torchvision==0.16.0+cu121
      - typing-extensions==4.4.0
      - urllib3==1.26.13
prefix: C:\Anaconda3\envs\win11pytorchgpu
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).